# how to open login modal on try to access protected routes in next js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, modal-dialog

In my website, I use login form inside a modal instead of a login page. my question is how to open this login modal if a user try to access a protected route or even try to do some actions that need to be authenticated first (bookmark or like an item without being logged in)?
one thing that comes to my mind is that inside my middleware redirect the user to the same page with adding a login=true param and then read from queryparam and show the modal. but i don't even know if it is a good idea or not? any other solution?
I'm using Nextjs 13.4 and react 18.2.

```
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const { url, nextUrl, cookies } = request;
  const { value: token } = cookies.get('accessToken') ?? { value: null };

  const hasVerifiedToken = token;
  const isAuthPageRequested = protectedRoutes.includes(
    request.nextUrl.pathname
  );

  if (isAuthPageRequested) {
    if (!hasVerifiedToken) {
      const response = NextResponse.next();
      response.cookies.delete('token');
      return response;
    }

    return;
  }

  if (!hasVerifiedToken) {
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(nextUrl.searchParams);
    searchParams.set('next', nextUrl.pathname);
    searchParams.set('login', 'true'); // Add the login query parameter and then read it inside my pages to show modal
    const response = NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL(`/home?${searchParams}`, url)
    );
    response.cookies.delete('token');

    return response;
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = { matcher: ['/profile/:path*', '/protected/:path*'] };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using React Context and hooks to handle the authentication status and modal visibility. This way, you can manage the state globally and avoid passing query parameters between pages.
AuthContext code concept,

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react'

const AuthContext = createContext(undefined)

export const AuthProvider= ({ children }) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false)
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext)
```

Then wrap your app with the AuthProvider...
Then after successful login you can set isAuthenticated as true.
Then use the useAuth hook in your protected routes or components,

```js
// ...your protected route or component...
import { useAuth } from 'path-to-your-authContext'

function ProtectedRoute() {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth()

  // Redirect or show modal based on isAuthenticated state.

  return <div>Your protected content here</div>
}
```